# Apache ActiveMQ fall back mechanism

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am using Apache Active MQ with Spring..... the problem I am facing is that I am creating producer on one machine let say Machine1 and I am creating one consumer on second machine let say Machine2...
I am creating producer on Machine1 by calling a simple servlet call.... and then create a consumer on Machine2....
Problem I am facing is that suppose in anyway if my producer is not able to send any data packet in specified time duration then I want to delete my consumer and Queue from Machine2...
Is there anyway I can set my Consumer and Queue to get auto delete and perform some business logic if I do not get any packet from producer in a specified time duration....

```
connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_USER,ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_PASSWORD,ConnectorURL);
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(transacted, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
destination = session.createQueue(queueID+"");
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
```

basically this code create consumer for my application....then I assign this consumer to my application listener that listen if producer send any message to consumer....

```
ScenarioExecutionQueueListenerImpl executionQueueListener = new ScenarioExecutionQueueListenerImpl(scenario,result, host);
beanFactory.autowireBean(executionQueueListener);
connection.setExceptionListener(executionQueueListener);
Message message = consumer.receive();
consumer.setMessageListener(executionQueueListener);
executionQueueListener.setConsumer(consumer);
executionQueueListener.onMessage(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not setup a messagelistener for that case, but just use the consumer.receive() method. The MessageListener is more for time independent/asynchronous consuming.

```
public void run(){
  Message m = consumer.receive(timeout_value_in_millisec);
  if( m != null ){
     // got a message, handle it.
     processMessage(msg);
  }else{
     // no message received in specified time, 
  }
  // close session, connection etc.
}

public void processMessage(Message msg){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply... I will check out this one....:)
One more thing I want to know is how I can delete the queue I have created to receive the messages.... either from consumer end or producer end

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...But in my case messages always be asynchronous and multiple messages... I just want to make sure that my listener should trigger and roll back everything if it didn't receive any message in a specified duration... also how I can delete the queues that I have created to receive the messages either from producer end or consumer end....

Comment: Queues in ActiveMQ does not need deletion or creation explicitly. They exist only when they are used. Read: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html